# Spring kafka message deserialization fails because the content-type is set to application/json

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am sending a message to Kafka as follows:

```
private KafkaTemplate<String, MyMessage > kafkaTemplate;

public void sendMessage(MyMessage data) {

    Message<MyMessage > message = MessageBuilder
            .withPayload(data)
            .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC,topic)
            .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY,data.getKey())
            .build();
    kafkaTemplate.send(message);
```

I have my own custom de/serializer for MyMessage, The key is a simple String

I am trying to process the message as follows:

```
@StreamListener
    public void process(@Input("input") KStream<String,MyMessage> myStream){
            final Serde<String> stringSerde = Serdes.String();
            final MyMessageSerde myMessageSerde = new MyMessageSerde();
            myStream
                    .groupBy((key,value)-> value.getObjectKey(), Serialized.with(stringSerde,myMessageSerde))
                    .aggregate(ArrayList::new,
                            (newKey,val,agg) -> {
                                agg.add(val);
                                return agg;
                            },
                            Materialized.<String, ArrayList<MyMessage>, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("object-keys")
                                    .withKeySerde(stringSerde)
                                    .withValueSerde(new ArrayListSerde(myMessageSerde)));

    ...
    interface MyStreamProcessor {
        @Input("input")
        KStream<?, ?> input();
    }
```

This is failing with a deserialization error and after debugging I see the reason is that the content-type header of the message is set to application/json and therefore it is trying to deserialize the message as JSON. How does the content-type header get set and how can I override it? I am not sending the messages as JSON but rather as a byte[] like regular Kafka messages so I want my custom de/serializer to be used

What is even stranger is that if I change this to a KTable it works fine.

```
@StreamListener
public void process(@Input("input") KTable<String,MyMessage> myTable){
        final Serde<String> stringSerde = Serdes.String();
        final MyMessageSerde myMessageSerde = new MyMessageSerde();
        KStream<String,MyMessage> myStream = myTable.toStream();
        myStream
                .groupBy((key,value)-> value.getObjectKey(), Serialized.with(stringSerde,myMessageSerde))
                .aggregate(ArrayList::new,
                        (newKey,val,agg) -> {
                            agg.add(val);
                            return agg;
                        },
                        Materialized.<String, ArrayList<MyMessage>, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("object-keys")
                                .withKeySerde(stringSerde)
                                .withValueSerde(new ArrayListSerde(myMessageSerde)));

...
interface MyStreamProcessor {
    @Input("input")
    KTable<?, ?> input();
}
```

Why with a KTable is the message deserialized correctly? What is the difference in the behavior between a KStream and a KTable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by doing the following:

1. set the input content type header in my application.yml file as follows:
   `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.content-type: application/mymessage`
2. Create a CustomMessageConverter which extends AbstractMessageConverter to convert from a byte[] to MyMessage. It also defines the new MimeType

`public MyMappingConverter() {
     super(new MimeType("application", "mymessage"));
 }`

3. Create a MessageConverter bean

`@Bean
 @StreamMessageConverter
 public MessageConverter myMessageConverter() {
     return new MyMessageConverter();
 }`

I still have no idea why I had to do all of this for a KStream but not for a KTable, if anyone can explain that it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It works because you specify your custom (de)serialization in the `.group` method.
Take a look at [this](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_kafka_streams_properties) and [this](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_inbound_deserialization) part of the docs to see how you can specify your custom value serde.

Comment: I added to my application.yml file. I am still getting the same exception where it is trying to parse JSON.


`spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.nativeDecoding: true
  spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.key.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
  spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.value.serde: com.MyMessageSerde`

Comment: The custom deserialization is specified in the group method whether it starts off as a KTable or a KStream. Why does it work when it starts as a KTable and fails when it starts as a KStream?